# Setting absolute cursor position using python uvdev

Tags: python, linux, evdev

I'm trying to simulate a graphics tablet in python, and as a result, I need to be able to set the absolute position of the cursor. I have tried [python-evdev](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [python-libevdev](https://python-libevdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), but I'm unable to set the absolute position. Wring values to the EV_ABS ABS_X and ABS_Y simply doesn't take any effect on a cursor position. It worth mentioning that simulated buttons and relative positioning work perfectly.

I'm using Manjaro 4.19 with Gnome on x11.

I would appreciate any help and thank you in advance.

Here's simple code which must be able to set the absolute cursor position, but it's not.

```py
from evdev import UInput, AbsInfo, ecodes as e
import pyautogui
import subprocess
import time

cap = {
    e.EV_KEY : [e.BTN_TOUCH],
    e.EV_ABS : [
        (e.ABS_X, AbsInfo(0, 0, 4080, 0, 0, 5080)),         
        (e.ABS_Y, AbsInfo(0, 0, 4080, 0, 0, 5080)),
        (e.ABS_PRESSURE, AbsInfo(0, 0, 2040, 0, 0, 0))
    ]
}

ui = UInput(cap, name='example-device', version=0x3)

for i in range(0,10):
    # assign driver to the default display
    time.sleep(0.5)
    process = subprocess.Popen(["xinput", "list"], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = process.stdout.read().decode("utf-8")
    print(output)
    if "example-device" in output:
        print(output)
        subprocess.Popen([
            "xinput",
            "map-to-output",
            f"pointer:example-device",
            "eDP1"
        ])
        break
else:
    raise Exception("Can't map device to display.")

# print cursor position befor cahnge
print(pyautogui.position())

# move mouse cursor
ui.write(e.EV_ABS, e.ABS_X, 20)
ui.write(e.EV_ABS, e.ABS_Y, 20)
ui.syn()
# print cursor position after cahnge
print(pyautogui.position())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I think to solve this you need to add BTN_TOOL_PEN to EV_KEY. At least this is worked for me. If you are interested you can see the whole project on [my github](https://github.com/alex-s-v/10moons-driver).